# Looping and adding together the values generated

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have just started learning javascript, and I've hit a bit of a roadblock whilst designing the logic behind a 10 pin bowling scorecard. I would be really grateful if someone could help me figure out how, instead of my messy code below for the totalScore function, I could use a for loop that will add all of the values together. The code that I have so far is as follows. Thank you in advance!

```
function Game() {
    this.scorecard = []
};


Game.prototype.add = function(frame) {
    this.scorecard.push(frame)
};

Game.prototype.totalScore = function() {
(this.scorecard[0].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
(this.scorecard[1].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
(this.scorecard[2].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
(this.scorecard[3].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
(this.scorecard[4].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
(this.scorecard[5].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
};


function Frame() {};

Frame.prototype.score = function(first_roll, second_roll) {
this.rollOne = first_roll;
this.rollTwo = second_roll;
return this
};

Frame.prototype.isStrike = function() {
return (this.rollOne === 10);
};

Frame.prototype.isSpare = function() {
return (this.rollOne + this.rollTwo === 10) && (this.rollOne !== 10)
};
```

Comment: I notice you are using `===` and `!==` which check for type as well as value. Your scores will be integer values, and it's unusual to check for type with well constructed code. Stick to `==` and `!=` unless you have good reason to make the code less efficient.

Comment: @WeatherVane: *"it's unusual to check for type with well constructed code"* I disagree, IMO using strict comparison is a characteristic of well constructed code. *"unless you have good reason to make the code less efficient"* What makes you think that strict comparison would be less efficient?

Comment: Because it takes more execution time. Javascript is an interpreted langauge. Strict directives are intended to guard against coders who can't construct their programs well, or library users who misuse them.

Comment: Thank you both for your advice. Always great to get a variety of opinions, particularly as I'm just starting out :)

Comment: Javascript does not declare data types, they are interpreted from context and converted as required. It's the opposite of "strong typing". So `===` and `!==` are used to ensure that data from extraneous sources do fit your data model strictly. But usually, it's not necessary when you are providing the data, in this case 10.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Just because you don't have to declare data types, doesn't mean that JavaScript doesn't have them. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8. In both cases (loose and strict comparison), the engine will first check which types the values have. In case of loose comparison it will perform type conversion if the values are not of the same type. In case of strict comparison it will immediately return `false`. *"Javascript is an interpreted langauge."* That doesn't have anything to do with strict or loose comparison, since it happens at runtime.

Comment: @Felix Kling - "It happens at runtime". That's why I said it was less efficient.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think you misunderstood me. Both, loose and strict comparison, perform type checks at run time! The difference is that loose comparison *additionally* does type conversion. To get further possible misunderstandings out of the way, I refer you to the specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3, http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example above.

Replace this:

```js
Game.prototype.totalScore = function() {
(this.scorecard[0].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
(this.scorecard[1].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
(this.scorecard[2].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
(this.scorecard[3].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
(this.scorecard[4].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
(this.scorecard[5].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo)+
};
```

With this:

```js
Game.prototype.totalScore = function() {
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i<6; i++) {
    result += this.scorecard[i].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo;
  }
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Game.prototype.totalScore = function() {
    total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < this.scorecard.length; i++)
    {
       total +=this.scorecard[i].rollOne + this.scorecard[0].rollTwo;
    }
    return total;
};
```